# Canvas starts to lag after some time

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Reproduction: focus your mouse on canvas , then spin your mouse in circles for ~15 sec. At first you'll notice how things are smooth. After some time it starts to lose its smoothness and becomes really laggy.

Part of the js function came from the following answer

[Make moving Rect more smooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36981848/make-moving-rect-more-smooth)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

var x;
var y;

var tx = tx || 0;
var ty = ty || 0;

var xDir;
var yDir;

function followMouse(e) {
  x = e.offsetX;
  y = e.offsetY;
  moveObject();
}

function moveObject() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var scale =  0.2 * Math.max(canvas.width, canvas.height);
  xDir = 0;
  yDir = 0;
  xDir = (x - tx) / scale;
  yDir = (y - ty) / scale;
  tx = tx != x ? tx + xDir : tx;
  ty = ty != y ? ty + yDir : ty;
  ctx.fillRect(tx - 25, ty + 25, 50, 10);
  if (tx != x || ty != y) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(moveObject);
  }
}

function resizeCanvas() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
};

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', _.throttle(function(e) {
  followMouse(e);
}, 30));

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

resizeCanvas();
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Is it lagging, or is the rectangle just getting too close the the mouse that the movement no longer seems fluid?

Comment: `moveObject` starts a loop, and each time you move the mouse, you start a new `moveObject` loop. This means that you will end up with thousands of loops in few seconds...

Comment: @FezVrasta So what should I do to "destroy" it and start a new one.

Comment: I would put `cancelAnimationFrame` inside the followMouse function

Comment: Well you're are starting a new loop at every mousemove (which may happen 100 times per seconds on some devices), so luckily enough, you do throttle it, but still, there are as much loops as non-throttled events : a lot. Why do you make a loop of it btw?

Comment: @Kaiido I kinda copied that philosophy from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations

Comment: Yes, that's the good way you start an animation loop. But you are starting a new one at each mousemove event. That's bad.

Comment: So I should just cancel it like Fez said?

Comment: or not start it at all

Comment: I dont think I can do what I want without it. I want the rect to follow my mouse with a delay. I dont think thats possible without this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens as for each `mousemove` a new loop is started. These loops will accumulate and eventually slow things down.

To solve you can implement `cancelAnimationFrame()` by doing:

```
...
var timer;

function followMouse(e) {
  x = e.offsetX;
  y = e.offsetY;
  cancelAnimationFrame(timer);
  moveObject();
}
```

Then store timer reference in the main loop:

```
...
timer = requestAnimationFrame(moveObject);
```

This will abort the current request for frame update and allow you to start a new loop without accumulating calls.

For this reason you would also have to initialize `x` and `y` since they are not initialized otherwise until the mouse has been moved (which is of course no guarantee).

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
```

Note: A side-effect of this correction is that now the movement is only calculated once per frame. When accumulated the movement got calculated many times per frame. To compensate adjust the scale to a lower value (shown below).

### Modified example

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var x = 0;
var y = 0;

var tx = tx || 0;
var ty = ty || 0;

var xDir;
var yDir;

var timer;

function followMouse(e) {
  x = e.clientX;
  y = e.clientY;
  cancelAnimationFrame(timer);
  moveObject();
}

function moveObject() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var scale = 0.02 * Math.max(canvas.width, canvas.height);
  xDir = 0;
  yDir = 0;
  xDir = (x - tx) / scale;
  yDir = (y - ty) / scale;
  tx = tx != x ? tx + xDir : tx;
  ty = ty != y ? ty + yDir : ty;
  ctx.fillRect(tx - 25, ty + 25, 50, 10);
  if (tx != x || ty != y) {
    timer = requestAnimationFrame(moveObject);
  }
}

function resizeCanvas() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
};

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', _.throttle(function(e) {
  followMouse(e);
}, 30));

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

resizeCanvas();
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. 
I've noticed I actually never get to have tx=x and ty=y. Which is bad cause I wan't to have a case where object get's to the position of the mouse. You've also slowed down the object?

Comment: @Paran0a the slow down is simply because the loop executes one/frame. When accumulated the calculations happened many times per frame. You can compensate by adjusting the scale value.